How to play AIFF format audio file in AndroidX Media3 ExoPlayer?
I am trying to make a ionic cordova plugin using AndroidX Media3 Exoplayer for android now.
During the development, I faced one challenge: AIFF format audio file is not played by ExoPlayer.
Below is the detailed issue logs:
ExoPlayerImplInternal    io.ionic.starter    E  Playback error
    androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
    at androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleIoException(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:652)
    at androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:622)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
Caused by: androidx.media3.exoplayer.source.UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available extractors (FlvExtractor, FlacExtractor, WavExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, AmrExtractor, PsExtractor, OggExtractor, TsExtractor, MatroskaExtractor, AdtsExtractor, Ac3Extractor, Ac4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, AviExtractor, JpegExtractor) could read the stream.
    at androidx.media3.exoplayer.source.BundledExtractorsAdapter.init(BundledExtractorsAdapter.java:94)
    at androidx.media3.exoplayer.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1018)
    at androidx.media3.exoplayer.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)

How to solve this
Source Error. Caused by: androidx.media3.exoplayer.source.UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available extractors (FlvExtractor, FlacExtractor, WavExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, AmrExtractor, PsExtractor, OggExtractor, TsExtractor, MatroskaExtractor, AdtsExtractor, Ac3Extractor, Ac4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, AviExtractor, JpegExtractor) could read the stream.
issue ??
I used ProgressiveMediaSource and normal MediaSource to play the media/audio files.
I tested my code in various audio files like Mp3, Ogg, Wav, AAC, ALAC, M4A, AIFF, and etc. At first, some formats weren't working like AAC, ALAC, M4A, and AIFF. So, I used EXTENSION_RENDERER_MODE_PREFER to prefer the FfmpegAudioRenderer than MediaCodecRenderer to process the streaming of audio. After that, the issue with AAC, ALAC, M4A are fixed but AIFF still has issue.
Below, I provide the code of my project.
DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new ResolvingDataSource.Factory(httpDataSourceFactory, 
                dataSpec -> dataSpec.withRequestHeaders(getHeaders(accessToken, dataSpec.uri.toString())));
DefaultRenderersFactory renderersFactory = new DefaultRenderersFactory(context).setExtensionRendererMode(DefaultRenderersFactory.EXTENSION_RENDERER_MODE_PREFER);
player = new ExoPlayer.Builder(context, renderersFactory)
        .setMediaSourceFactory(new DefaultMediaSourceFactory(dataSourceFactory))
        .setLoadControl(loadControl)
        .build();

// some unimportant part...

List<MediaSource> mediaSources = new ArrayList<>();
if (trackUrl.startsWith("https")) { // If audio track is online source
    Log.d(TAG, "Creating ProgressiveMediaSource for: " + trackUrl);
    DataSource.Factory resolvingDataSourceFactory = new ResolvingDataSource.Factory(httpDataSourceFactory, dataSpec -> dataSpec.withRequestHeaders(getHeaders(headerToken, dataSpec.uri.toString())));

    ProgressiveMediaSource progressiveMediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(resolvingDataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(trackUrl));

    mediaSources.add(progressiveMediaSource);
} else {
    Log.d(TAG, "Creating MediaItem for local file: " + trackUrl);
    MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(trackUrl);
    MediaSource mediaSource = new DefaultMediaSourceFactory(context).createMediaSource(mediaItem);
    mediaSources.add(mediaSource);
}

player.setMediaSources(mediaSources);


public void playTrackByIndex(int index, long seekPosition) {
    player.seekTo(index, seekPosition);
    player.prepare();
    player.play();
}

I expect all media/audio track files including AIFF format to work fine without these errors in ExoPlayer.


